# Automatically retry request on other urls

Tags: javascript, request

Assume I have an application that relies on a service, of which there are many instances. I automatically want to retry the request on the next service's instance.

This is an example request:

```
var url = 'http://myservice1.com:3001'
function getItems() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url+'/api/items',(body,error) => {
      if(error) reject(error)
      else resolve(body)
    })
   })
}
```

Comment: @JaromandaX That's right. I used it for clearification because it might get more complex in there. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll change something, thats actually makes use of that :)

Comment: @JaromandaX I just went lazy and turned `request` that normally uses a callback into a promise function. Now it should make more sense

Comment: cool, will remove my comments :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wrapper for the Promise function, that executes the Promise function with multiple urls. [async-wrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-wrap) implements this.
You can use it like this:

```
function getItems(){
    var urls = getServiceUrls() // Returns array
    return coalesce(urls, requestItems)

    function requestItems(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(url+'/api/items', (body,error) => {
              if(error) reject(error)
              else resolve(body)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

> Disclaimer: I developed that package, because I had that problem and looked for a neat solution. I'm open for any other suggestions to address this problem.